R: Set the point size of PCA supplementary variables according to their number in my dataset
I am using factoextra and FactoMineR to run a PCA.
p <- fviz_pca_ind(res.afdm, col.ind.sup = "blue", repel = TRUE, labelsize = 3, label="none", alpha.ind ="contrib")
p <- fviz_add(p, res.afdm$quali.sup$coord, color = "red", labelsize = 3, repel = TRUE)
              
p

How do I set the size of the points representing suppllementary qualitative variables according to the total number of each modality in my dataset ? So that if a modality represents only 10 person compared to 100 for another modality, the size of the point will be set accordingly.
